# How can I incorporate "\t" into my for loop output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on some code that will cycle through a list and output the values. At the beginning of each iteration, I would also like the value to be indented. Here is the code I have so far:

```
pizzas = ['cheese','pepperoni','supreme']

print("My favorite pizzas are:")
for pizza in pizzas:
    print(\tpizza)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the \t:

```
print("\t"+pizza)
```

Check out some tutorials on print in python:

https://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php

Also, when you paste your code, make sure you use the formatting code elements, so people can see what it looks like as code.

Comment: Thank you! This one worked for me. This was my first question on Stack and I thought that I had gotten the formatting right but it appears not.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use f-string, which is more intuitive in the long run. But it requires new Python version

```
print (f"\t{pizza}")
```

Comment: That was my thought as well but the f string way didn't end up working as it just printed "pizza" and not the value for that iteration. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.6+ then you can use `f-strings` to format your strings. Also, here is the solution to your required problem.

```
pizzas = ['cheese', 'pepperoni', 'supreme']

print(f"My favorite pizzas are:", end="\t")
for pizza in pizzas:
  print(f"{pizza}", end=" ")
```

The `end` parameter is really helpful in terminating your `print()` function output.

Answer (score -1):

You could use \n instead of \t and it will switch to the next line
but u have to do like this print("/n" + pizza) with "\t" will work aswell

Comment: Thank you for the response! print("\t" + pizza) was the solutions that ended up working.